# Tamperproofing ASP.NET viewstate

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, iis

my team currently uses ASP.NET webforms in their existing project.
Some of this functionality stores values in the viewstate, I do not mind the values being base64 decode-able, but I do not want them to be able to be tampered with. I have added this code, but with different key values. ;)

```
<machineKey
    validationKey="DD913F8422F51CD25A5A94056B66BF314E51362F2AE67197FCD471A2745AA81AD6CDFB035065DA8906B86572635C0C77876C3694ECA39D99858D489CE6BDB35B"
    decryptionKey="1D80D6A0931A788BCDCB6E5EE9450C53436C02FED7675A0EE922801CDEF808FE"
    validation="SHA1"
    decryption="AES"
    />
```

Does this stop the viewstate from being tampered with. My understanding is the SHA1 hashes something to then check it has not being tampered with before accepting it as legit.

Also I believe this is vulnerable to the padded oracle attack in versions of IIS. Is installing the patch enough?

Comment: Enable the ViewStateMAC and your ViewState will be securely signed, making it impossible for website visitors to modify the ViewState before it's returned.

Comment: Is this enabled by default? Or do I have to set it in the web.config. Also will this have any sort of performance hit?

Comment: A good rule of thumb is that ANY time data goes over the wire outside of the web server or corporate network, it can be retrieved and manipulated by the user. Even if the data is encrypted. So if you're serious about protecting the data, then don't send it to the client in the first place.

Comment: How do I prevent the viewstate being seen client side then?

Comment: Google 'ViewStateMAC'; this is sufficient

Comment: @sh1rts This has already been mentioned, can you answer if it is enabled by default which I believe it is. What makes you think this is enough too?

Comment: It is enabled by default; you can override this as needed at page level, or turn it off for all pages in the <pages> section of web.config/<system.web>. I believe it is sufficient based on experience, I'm going to assume you're performing input validation so I don't need to mention that without doing so nothing is sufficient.

Comment: Yeah, I have no interest in turning it off. Just have old legacy pages using viewstate, which I hate but unable to change. Everything is input validated server side.